# How to map a callback of map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to render a item and your respective subitems, this is my list:

```
  const labelList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      tipo: 'Type 1',
      itens:
      [{
        id: 1,
        nameItem: 'Item 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        nameItem: 'item 2',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        nameItem: 'item 3',
      }],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      tipo: 'Type 2',
      itens:
      [{
        id: 1,
        nameItem: 'Item 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        nameItem: 'item 2',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        nameItem: 'item 3',
      }],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      tipo: 'Type 3',
      itens:
      [{
        id: 1,
        nameItem: 'Item 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        nameItem: 'item 2',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        nameItem: 'item 3',
      }],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      tipo: 'Type 4',
      itens:
      [{
        id: 1,
        nameItem: 'Item 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        nameItem: 'item 2',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        nameItem: 'item 3',
      }],
    },
  ];
```

So, I'm trying to display this data like this:

Type 1
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
Type 2
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
Type 3
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
Type 4
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3

This is my code:

```
{labelList.map(element => {
  return(            
      <p>{element.tipo}</p>

      {element.map(item => {
        return(
          <CheckboxField
            key={item.id}
            label={item.nameItem}                
          />
        )
      })}
  )})}
```

I'm using React, but it's a Javascript issue!

I'm trying to run a map (to render `itens`) with a callback `element` of `labelList.map()`. My code not works, but I believe that logic its appears like this.

Someone can help me?

Comment: it should be `elements.itens.map` not `elements.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map `itens` key instead of element only.

```
{labelList.map(element => {
  return(            
      <p>{element.tipo}</p>

      {element.itens.map(item => {
        return(
          <CheckboxField
            key={item.id}
            label={item.nameItem}                
          />
        )
      })}
  )})}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, you can iterate on element.itens not on element, so these is the correct code:

```
{labelList.map(element => {
return(            
  <p>{element.tipo}</p>

  {element.itens.map(item => {
    return(
      <CheckboxField
        key={item.id}
        label={item.nameItem}                
      />
    )
  })}
)})}
```